# Serializing transient field (field has String)

Tags: java, serialization

```
2 classes DOG and Collar
```

Dog HAS A Collar which is not serializable

Collar has String and int

QUES: HOW to serialize DOG object?
tried overriding writeObject and readObject but stuck when writing String member of collar
How to write and read it???

Here are the 2 classes

```
import java.io.*;

public class Dog implements Serializable{

String name;
transient Collar c;

public Dog(String name, Collar c){
    this.name = name;
    this.c =c;

}

public static void main(String args[]){

    Dog d = new Dog("DogsName",new Collar("CollarsColor",3));


    try {
        File f = new File("dogs.ser");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        oos.writeObject(d);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();



        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);


        Dog d2 =(Dog)ois.readObject();

        System.out.println(d2);
        ois.close();

    }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

}   


public class Collar {
String color;
int size;

public Collar(){        
    color= "White";
    size =10;
}

public Collar(String c,int s){
    color =c;
    size =s;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the field 'c' is marked transient, it will be passed over at serialization time. The quickest way to make this field serializable is to have the Collar class implement the Serializable interface. Since the Collar class only contains a String and an int, it will have no trouble being serialized.

If you wish to keep the Collar-type 'c' field as transient while still serializing its state, you can add getter methods for the data members of Collar and add readObject and writeObject methods to the **Dog** class like this:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) {
  try {
    os.defaultWriteObject();
    os.writeInt(c.getSize());
    os.writeObject(c.getColor());
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception
  }
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream is) {
  try {
    is.defaultReadObject();
    int collarSize = is.readInt();
    String collarColor = (String) is.readObject();
    this.c = new Collar(collarColor, collarSize);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception
  }
}
```

Comment: os.writeObject(c.getColor());

This is what is was looking for.
Used every other method to write string but this, THANKS KOTZ.

LOW rep otherwise would have marked the answer usefull

Comment: I believe you should still be able to accept the answer despite having low rep.

Answer (score 0):

if a member is transient it is not part of the serialization. So you loose your Collar reference. If you like to serialize it, too, remove the transient and make the Collar class implementing Serializable as well.

i'm not 100% sure, but if you use serialization you should always have a default constructor, since java has to create an instance of your class without any parameters

Comment: Lets assume we have no access to Collar class. We cant change it

Comment: When an instance of 
a serializable class is deserialized, the constructor does not run, and instance variables 
are NOT given their initially assigned values! Think about it—if the constructor 
were invoked, and/or instance variables were assigned the values given in their 
declarations, the object you're trying to restore would revert back to its original 
state, rather than coming back reflecting the changes in its state that happened 
sometime after it was created.

Comment: first - if you don't have access to it you are kind of lost, because the serialization API will not allow you to serialize it. 
second - that's why i was not 100% sure ;)